# How to get Retrofit success response status codes

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am not able to get success response status code from response like 200,201.. etc. As we can easily get error codes from `RetrofitError` class like `error.isNetworkError()` and `error.getResponse().getStatus()`. Is there any workaround for getting status codes?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

As per Retrofit 2.0.2, the call is now

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<YourModel> call, Response<YourModel> response) {
    if (response.code() == 200) {
       // Do awesome stuff
    } else {
       // Handle other response codes
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone :-)

**EDIT:** Many apps could also benefit from just checking for success (response code 200-300) in one clause, and then handling errors in other clauses, as 201 (Created) and 202 (Accepted) would probably lead to the same app logic as 200 in most cases.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<YourModel> call, Response<YourModel> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
       // Do awesome stuff
    } else if (response.code() == 401) {
       // Handle unauthorized
    } else {
       // Handle other responses
    }
}
```

Comment: `response.code == 401` should be `response.code() == 401`.

Comment: what class should I override this?

Comment: In which class does should i write this method ?

Comment: Can someone answer @KaranSharma's question, I am confused too...

My structure looks like this: Service -> DataSource -> Repository -> ViewModel -> Fragment

Answer (score 20):

You can get the status code in `success()` just like you do it in `failure()`

```
@Override
public void success(Object object, Response response) {
    response.getStatus() // returns status code integer
}
```

Since you have a `Response` object in success callback as `response.getStatus()`

**EDIT**

I assume you are using *okhttp* with *retrofit*.

*okhttp* has a powerful tool called `Interceptor`

You can catch the response before retrofits Callback and get status code from the response:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.interceptors().add(new  Interceptor(){
    @Override 
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException{

    Request request = chain.request();
    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
    response.code()//status code
    return response;

});

// then add it to you Restclient like this:
restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(URL_SERVER_ROOT)
                .setClient(new OkClient(client))  //plus your configurations       
                .build();
```

To learn more about interceptors visit [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors).

Comment: I didn't find any function response.getStatus(). I am using retrofit 1.9.0 ,which version are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.9.0 too. are you using the Callback interface?

Comment: Yes, but as per http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/Callback.html document we have two callbacks success and failure.As per definition we have will get Unsuccessful HTTP response due to network failure, non-2XX status code, or unexpected exception from failure but only Successful HTTP response from success.

Comment: ah sorry i didnt get the question right i think. now i will edit my answer

Comment: Yeh, actually just like failure status code i need success status codes for doing some operations on the basis of them. On other hand thanks for spending your time on it.

Comment: But I am pretty sure  success call back has 2 parameters 1st one is your type   2nd is the Response as the documentation says: success(T t, Response response)

Comment: Is there any complete tutorial for using Okhttp interceptor?

Comment: @AdarshYadav read that documentation again. on success you do receive the Response object that contains what you ask for.

Comment: The "T" is what you asked for, "Response" is as same as RetrofitError.getResponse. in response object you have status code. please try using it I am sure i am using it in my code.

Comment: @Ercan: above code works for me, now I am able to get status code but now my app start crashing Retrofit﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method POST must have a request body. I am using following combinations compile'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0' .Is this issue related to different versions.

Comment: I am not sure @AdarshYadav this looks like another question to me. It clearly states that post method lacking a body. Check your service method name and request. use restClient in full Log mode. I hope this helps you.

Comment: I Have fixed it by reducing versions to compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0' and compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0' .Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: RestAdapter is deprecated

Comment: Thanks for `Interceptor`. I found status code when parsed HTML instead of JSON. In this case it threw `JsonSyntaxException`.

Answer (score 9):

i achieved it by following codes:

```
public abstract class BaseCallBack<T> {

    public abstract void onSuccess(Response<T> response);
    public abstract void onFailure(Response<T> response);
}

public abstract class SuccessCallback<T> extends BaseCallBack<T> implements Callback<T>{


    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {

        if(response.code()>= 400 && response.code() < 599){
             onFailure(response);
        }
        else {
            onSuccess(response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t){

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Response<T> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Response<T> response) {

    }
}
```

When the rest api returns 400 etc then the onFailure method will be call by default. If you wanna do something onsuccess:(when returns 200 etc)

```
 ServiceConnector.api.getHomePage().enqueue(new SuccessCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Response<Void> response) {
            super.onSuccess(response);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

---

> you should get exception code iin onError response

```
HttpException httpException =((HttpException) e).code();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30665677)