# http status code even without error response retrofit

Tags: android, http-status-code-404, retrofit

I'm working with Retrofit 1.9

I'm calling a webservice which never send response body, just a 200 when it's okey and a 404 when it's not.
To handle 202 success it's easy since the Retrofit callback already has a method "success" called when the code is between 200 and 300.
But the issue I have is with this part :

```
@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    error.getResponse().getStatus();
}
```

how should I get the http response code to check if it's a 404 or a 500(or whatever else) since the error.getResponse() is null ? I'm trying to do this to correctly notify the user.

Comment: Is error.getResponse().getStatus() not giving you a response code? thats strange

Comment: error.getResponse() return null so I can't really call getStatus();
The webservice I call don't have a Response Body, just return 200 or 404 Http code, it's a Delete webservice

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808083/how-to-get-retrofit-success-responce-status-codes

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not at the office anymore, I won't be able to know if it works until Monday

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks !