# Handling Retrofit status codes without a pojo class

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I got the following response from my server: status code `201 Created`.
There is no actual response (returned object, etc.), so there is not need to create a POJO class.

So, I don't know how I should handle this status code without creating a POJO class. Is there any option to make write the code without using a POJO class?

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808083/how-to-get-retrofit-success-responce-status-codes

Comment: Use `Call<Void>`.

Comment: have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request/36821182#36821182

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrofit API has [Response](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/) class that can encapsulate your response.

As long as you don't want to bother with the response data you can implement your service as:

```
interface CustomService {
    @GET("whatever")
    Call<Response<Void>> getAll();

    // Or using RxJava:
    @GET("whatever")
    Single<Response<Void>> getRxAll();
}
```

Then implement your callback:

```
private Callback<Response<Void>> responseHandler = new Callback<Response<Void>>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<Response<Void>> call, Response<Response<Void>> response) {
    final int code = response.code();
    // TODO: Do whatever you want with the response code.
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<Response<Void>> call, Throwable t) {
      // TODO: Handle failure.
  }
}
```

Or reactive consumer:

```
private Consumer<Response<Void>> responseRxHandler = new Consumer<Response<Void>>() {
  @Override
  public void accept(Response<Void> response) throws Exception {
      final int responseCode = response.code();
      // TODO: Do whatever you want with the response code.
  }
};
```

Debugging result:[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following code.

Can get the response without a POJO class by getting using ResponseBody format and then you can parse it normally like ordinary JSON parsing.

Api Call:

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.callLogin(AppConstants.mApiKey, model_obj);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if(response.code() == 201)
    {
     JSONObject jobjresponse = null;
    try {
            jobjresponse = new JSONObject(mResponse.body().string());
            String status = jobjresponse.getString("status");
            JSONObject  result = jobjresponse.getJSONObject("results");
                    String  msg = result.getString(“msg”);  
} catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Retrofit Interface class:

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"})
@POST("v1/auth/")
public Call<ResponseBody> callLogin(@Query("key") String key, @Body LoginModel body);

public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(“base url”)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
}
```

Sample Response:

```
{ "status":"true", "result":{"msg”:”created successfully”} }
```