# How get response from GET url using retrofit

Tags: android

I want to get response from my Get api using retrofit but i don't know how to check `status:success` so its show null response below given full code with my api response,

**My response is :**

```
{
   status: "success",
   data: [
           {
            Country_id: "1",
            Country_name: "Maldives",
            Continent_name: "Asia",
           }
]
}
```

**My Interface class :**

```
public interface GetDataService 
{
     @GET("/Webserices/country_random.php")
     Call<List<RetroPhoto>> getAllPhotos();
}
```

**POJO :**

```
public class RetroPhoto 
{
    @SerializedName("Country_id")
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("Country_name")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("Continent_name")
    private String name;

 public RetroPhoto(Integer id, String title, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.name= name;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

**Below is calling method in MainActivity class :**

```
    GetDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataService.class);
    Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call = service.getAllPhotos();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<RetroPhoto>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call, Response<List<RetroPhoto>> response) {
            progressDoalog.dismiss();
            Log.e("jellosdsd", "onResponse:********************* " + response.body());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDoalog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Above given full code but its show null response because i don't know how to check `status: "success"` and data array object in retrofit.

so please can anyone explain it how to check that in retrofit.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Retrofit success response status codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808083/how-to-get-retrofit-success-response-status-codes)

Answer (score 1):

Try to create your custom response class. It should look like something like this:

```
public class RetroPhotoResponse {

private String status;
private List<RetroPhoto> data;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public List<RetroPhoto> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<RetroPhoto> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

}

Comment: Then how make other data POJO class and how can i use in my mainactivity class.?

Comment: @SiddharthPatel instead of `Response<List<RetroPhoto>>` , try to use   `Response<RetroPhotoResponse>` and keep other classes same.