# Control errors on Retrofit calls like (404)

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to get the HttpResponse code and control the errors for display them to the user.

I have my static retrofit request:

```
    public class NetworkClient {

        //KEY: f663e4c56cc039c837109c82c78bbd69
        public static Retrofit getRetrofit(){

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    //                .client(OkHttpClient())
                    .build();

            return retrofit;
        }
```

And observable who takes the request returns me an observable:

```
public Observer<Response> getObserver(){
        Observer<Response> response = new Observer<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                Log.d("test", "onSubscribe");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Response response) {
                Log.d("test", "onNext");
                fragmentInterface.showMovies(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.d("test", "onError");
                e.printStackTrace();

                if(e instanceof HttpException){
                    int errorCode = ((HttpException) e).response().code();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.d("test", "onComplete");
            }
        };

        return response;
    }
```

I see i can get the error from the onError, but i see i can have a class to get all type errors.

Comment: Your baseUrl is invalid (404 is when the server doesn't know what you are looking for). What is the expected api url?

Comment: ? I know this. But i think you confuse my question. I want to know how control the callback with retrofit and rxjava

Comment: I see. Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808083/how-to-get-retrofit-success-response-status-codes