# How to get HTTP status code (400, 200...) on Observer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

Is there a way to get HTTP Status code (like 200, 400...) before you observe a live data ?

This is my implementation :

**Result**

```
sealed class Result<out T: Any> {

    data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T?): Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception): Result<Nothing>()
}
```

**BaseRepository**

```
open class BaseRepository {

    suspend fun <T: Any> safeApiCall(call: suspend () -> Response<T>, errorMessage: String): T? {
        val result: Result<T> = safeApiResult(call, errorMessage)
        var data: T? = null

        when(result) {
            is Result.Success ->
                data = result.data
            is Result.Error -> {
                Logger.getLogger("1.DataRepository").log(Level.INFO, "$errorMessage & Exception - ${result.exception}")
            }
        }

        return data
    }

    private suspend fun <T: Any> safeApiResult(call: suspend ()-> Response<T>, errorMessage: String): Result<T> {
        val response = call.invoke()

        if (response.isSuccessful) return Result.Success(response.body())

        return Result.Error(IOException("Error Occurred during getting safe Api result, Custom ERROR - $errorMessage"))
    }
}
```

**My repository**

```
class UserRepository (private val api : UserService) : BaseRepository() {

    suspend fun getFavorites() : MutableList<Favorite>? {
        return safeApiCall(
            call = {api.getFavorites().await()},
            errorMessage = "Error Fetching Favorites"
        )?.toMutableList()
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class UserViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val parentJob = Job()

    private val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Default

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)

    private val repository: UserRepository = UserRepository(ApiFactory.Apifactory.userService)

    val favoritesLiveData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Favorite>>()

    fun fetchFavorites() {
        scope.launch {
            val favorites = repository.getFavorites()
            favoritesLiveData.postValue(favorites)
        }
    }
}
```

**In my code I do something like this :**

```
userViewModel.fetchFavorites()

userViewModel.favoritesLiveData.observe(this, Observer {

})
```

Where can I check the status code ? I can't figure out where to implement the status code return.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing it from live data as it's the last (or to be exact one before the last) step your data is presented to the user by populating the views in your activity/fragment etc...

In order to accomplish this, you need to check it in your repository or your viewModel.

before you parse your result to your models you can check the code of your response

Something like

```
public abstract class SuccessCallback<T> extends BaseCallBack<T> implements Callback<T>{


    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {

        if(response.code()>= 400 && response.code() < 599){
             onFailure(response);
        }
        else {
            onSuccess(response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t){

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Response<T> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Response<T> response) {

    }
}
```

You can see other solutions (including this one) from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808083/how-to-get-retrofit-success-response-status-codes)

**Edit**

I think you will have access to the code from the response object in `safeApiResult` function. Just try `response.code`

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't use the same implementation as yours, what's its equivalent in the same way as mine? (I edited the question).